# Using \multicolumn

Tags: pdftex

I am trying to produce a more compact header for my table, i.e. less space at the top of the column headings. However, when I use `\multicolumn` with:

```
\multicolumn{3}{|p{3cm}|}{\centering Synthetic Beam \\ ($\theta_{\rm x}$) & ($\theta_{\rm y}$) &  P.A. \\ ($\prime\prime$) & ($\prime\prime$)  & $^{\circ}$}
```

I get an error. What am I doing incorrectly? Is this good syntax with `\multicolumn`?

Comment: `\multicolumn` merges several columns to *one* column. Therefore `&` cannot be used.